# How to delete a line with clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

I'm creating a clang-tidy checker to replace a function with another function. The replaced function is relying on a `using namespace ..;` declaration. As part of my clang-tidy checker I also want to remove that declaration.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace ns1::ns2; // declaration I want to remove
using namespace std;
```

If have it currently working to remove the SourceRange of `using namespace ns1::ns2` and trailing `;`. But this leaves a empty line behind as this diff shows:

```diff
 #include <filesystem>

 namespace fs = std::filesystem;
-using namespace ns1::ns2;
+
 using namespace std;
```

I achieved it with clang-tidy `check()`:

```cpp
void RenameFunctionCheck::check(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result)
{
  // rename function

  if (const auto *MatchNS = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<UsingDirectiveDecl>("replaceNS")) {
    ASTContext *Context = Result.Context;
    SourceLocation Semicolon = Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(
      MatchedNS->getIdentLocation(), 0, Context->getSourceManager(),
      Context->getLangOpts());
    
    diag(MatchedNS->getUsingLoc(), "obsolete nested namespace ns1::ns2")
        << FixItHint::CreateRemoval(MatchedNS->getSourceRange())
        << FixItHint::CreateRemoval(Semicolon);
  }
}
```

How do I delete the whole line?